# Playing scales on the piano with both hands at different rates

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Say I am playing both bass and treble on the piano. With my right hand, every time I reach the next C up, I walk my fingers back down to middle C:

|Cm|D|E|F|G|A|B|C1|B|A|G|F|E|D|Cm|

or

|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|7|6|5|4|3|2| and repeat

I do this with both hands, and for every 3 notes with my right hand, I progress one note with my left. How many cycles until both hands land on the 1st note in their respective scales?

What I have worked out is that the (total notes played by the right hand) - (total notes played by left hand) = 14x where x is any integer

Comment: Won't you then complete one left-hand cycle in exactly the time it takes you to make three right-hand cycles?

Comment: 123.456.787.654.321.234.567.876.543.212.345.678.765.432.123

Comment: the problem is that the bass note _coincides_ with each 3rd note and doesn't just follow it. As I have shown with the sequence above, 3 cycles isn't enough. The left hand **1** would fall on the second to last **2** of the right hand. Sorry about the above comment, I didn't realize ENTER functioned the way it did.

Answer (score 1):

(Perhaps this ought to be a comment, but I need more formatting than comments allow).

Three cycles of the right hand ought to be enough, or I don't understand your specification:

```
cdefgabCbagfedcdefgabCbagfedcdefgabCbagfedc
c  d  e  f  g  a  b  C  b  a  g  f  e  d  c
```

If you don't start the two cycles at the same time, then they will never synchronize, because each start of the lower cycle will happen at the same position in the higher cycle as the previous one.